# jQuery access to elements created from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined and created `<input>` elements in table with ids like `id="value0"`, `id="value1"`, ...

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
     $('#development_mapping tbody').append(
        '<tr><td>'+ result[i].visual_feature+'</td> \n\
           <td><input name="data-feature_x"  id="value'+i+'"/></td>\n\
         </tr>'
     );
 };
```

Now I want to access those ids. And here is a problem. I do not understand why this code is not working:

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    var tmp_index = '#value' +i; 
    $(tmp_index).keydown(function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            execute();
            console.log(tmp_index, " ok!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How isn't it working? Errors? Wrong outcome? Nothing happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental `id` attributes are never a good idea, mostly because it leads to issues like the above, and also because they are a pain to maintain. Use a class to group the elements instead - it's what classes are designed for. Also, because these elements are being dynamically appended after page load, you need to use a delegated event. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    $('#development_mapping tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ result[i].visual_feature+'</td><td><input name="data-feature_x" class="feature"/></td></tr>');
};

$('#development_mapping tbody').on('keydown', '.feature', function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        execute();
        console.log("ok!");}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the inputs are added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#development_mapping tbody').on('keydown', tmp_index, function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        execute();
        console.log(this.id, " ok!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of a closure variable scope issue... in this case you can use `this.id` to access the elemetn id

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    $('#value' + i).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            execute();
            console.log(this.id, " ok!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here elements are created after page-load, so events will not be binded with those.
Use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function for attaching events on dynamically created elements.

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   var tmp_index = '#value' +i; 
    jQuery("#development_mapping tbody").on("keydown",tmp_index,function(e) { 
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {execute();
                    console.log(tmp_index, " ok!");}
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this code is not working. I mean my function execute